# Bootstrap Alpha Carousel Fade Transition

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using an unmodified Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.3.

I implemented a carousel, nearly the same as here (http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/).

Well, in Bootstrap V3.X.X you could change the transition easily, but now I can't figure out how to change the transition to "fade".
I tried adapting this example: (http://codepen.io/zlobae/pen/xwVqGy/) but I had no luck.
This part

```
.carousel-fade {
    .carousel-item {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity .75s ease-in-out;

        &.active {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
}
```

doesn't seem to work properly.

Does anyone know how to achieve a fading transition?

EDIT: HTML is at the moment for reasons of reproducibility the same as in the Codepen Page:

```
<div data-ride="carousel" class="carousel carousel-fade" id="carousel-example-captions">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li class="active" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#carousel-example-captions"></li>
      <li data-slide-to="1" data-target="#carousel-example-captions" class=""></li>
      <li data-slide-to="2" data-target="#carousel-example-captions" class=""></li>
    </ol>
    <div role="listbox" class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>First slide label</h3>
          <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Second slide label</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Third slide label</h3>
          <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a data-slide="prev" role="button" href="#carousel-example-captions" class="left carousel-control">
      <span aria-hidden="true" class="icon-prev"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a data-slide="next" role="button" href="#carousel-example-captions" class="right carousel-control">
      <span aria-hidden="true" class="icon-next"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

The Carousel shows up properly but it does not show the fade property. Seems to be a compatibility issue between v4.0.0 and v4.0.3

Comment: Can you post your HTML? That could help a lot

Comment: Have you tried changing `.slide` class to `.carousel-fade` on your `<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">`?

Comment: Changed the question a bit. Copied the codepen code and it is not working, seems to be a compatibility issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using the following CSS

```
// Carousel fade transition
.carousel-fade {
    .carousel-item {
        display: block !important;
        position: absolute;
        transform: none;
        perspective: none;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity .75s ease-in-out;

        &.active {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
}
```